# Order Swift array by two fields

Tags: swift

I have this problem. I have this vector with two fields for position:

```
fecha:  9/10/2017
turno:  0
fecha:  9/10/2017
turno:  6
fecha:  9/10/2017
turno:  17
fecha:  10/10/2017
turno:  17
```

And for order this I am using this code:

```
self.TodasMisCitas.sort {
    if ($0.fecha as Date == $1.fecha as Date) {
        return ($0.turno) > ($1.turno)
    }
    return ($0.fecha) > ($1.fecha)
}
```

This is the output:

[image: i don't upload image :( see in this link please]

The correct output for me will be:

```
martes 10/10/2017
lunes 09/10/2017 a las 10:00
lunes 09/10/2017 a las 11:30
lunes 09/10/2017 a las 16:00
```

Anybody know what's happening?

Comment: So how exactly do you want the sort to work?

Comment: When you compare the dates with == maybe you should take into account the day not the entire date.

Comment: Explain what is exactly `fecha`. Your code should work, but if `fecha` doesn't hold hours/minutes (while a `Date` object does), but just the day it won't. And you mean that if the day/hour/minute are the same, then you check the `turno`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compare the dates with == maybe you should take into account the day not the entire date. I couldn't compile but I think it should be something like this:

```
self.TodasMisCitas.sort {
    if Calendar.current.compare($0.fecha, to: $1.fecha, toGranularity: .day) == .orderedSame {
        return ($0.turno) > ($1.turno)
    }
    return ($0.fecha) > ($1.fecha)
}
```